# Lightbox overlay remains after closing, page 100% height

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Hei, I am using Wordpress and a theme called Stockholm.

The problem is that whenever I click on the image a lightbox appears. When closing the lightbox or clicking outside the lightbox, I would assume the darker overlay to disappear, but it doesn't do that. it stays and it won't let me click anywhere else. I can't find the fault neither in js or css.

This is the page:

http://plaaditood.ee/portfolio_page/vaana-moisa-tolla-kuur-looduskivi-paigaldus-80-m2/

Another issue is with the height of the webpage. It doesn't have enough content to fill the height 100%. Making the body's min-height: 100% didn't work.

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: Check this article out for solving your height problem: http://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

Comment: I suggest to remove this one :
`body div.pp_overlay, body div.pp_default .pp_content_container .pp_details 
{
  opacity: .7!important;
}`

it keeps black screen with opacity 0.7

Comment: @Raźnyy the overlay would still exist and thusly block mouse input to the page

Comment: Removing that line will only make it work in the web edit mode ( chrome i.e). If i remove the line from the code permanently the overlay of the lightbox is always gone. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

you might try adding the following jQuery , provided that there will only be one lightbox open at any time:

```
$(document).on("click", ".pp_close", function(){
$(".pp_overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @K'K make sure you add it towards the end of your page. If it doesn't work, try `$(document).on("click", ".pp_close", function(){ $(".pp_overlay").fadeOut(); });`

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the lightbox not closing the grey overlay, it seems like you have the prettyphoto javascript twice on your page.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://plaaditood.ee/assets/themes/stockholm/js/plugins.js?ver=4.2.2'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://plaaditood.ee/assets/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/prettyphoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js?ver=4.3.4'></script>
```

That may be what is causing the issue. You may also double check your implementation if after you remove one of the instances and it still doesn't fix the problem.

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation

In regards to the footer not staying to the bottom of the screen when there isn't as much content to push it to the bottom, you may try this:
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: Other plugins are not active. Could it be that a formerly used lightbox plugin has left some lines in the code?

Comment: If you see this file:
http://plaaditood.ee/assets/themes/stockholm/js/plugins.js?ver=4.2.2

That file is being loaded on your page near the bottom of your source code. You can find Pretty Photo on there.

http://plaaditood.ee/assets/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/prettyphoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js?ver=4.3.4 is also on the bottom of your page.